# Searching a text file with a single line using regular expressions

Tags: command-line, text-processing

as far as i know all unix text processing utilities are reading one line at a time and performing one action on this line.

I have a huge file with a single line of text which contains several tokens im concerned with.

You can think of the content of the file as something like this:
xzxzxzzxzxAxzzBxzxCzxxzxxzxzzxzxzAzBzxxxxzzCzxzxzxzxzxxzz

I want to get the two strings between (A and B) and (B and C) for every occurrence of A.*B.*C.
In this example my desired output would be this:

xzz xzx

z zxxxxzz

How do i do this?

edit: sorry, i didn't make it clear. A, B and C are long Strings that can only be identified by regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there are many interesting answers using `awk`,`perl`,`sed`, and others.  Here is a rather simplistic options that uses `tr` to turn this problem back into one a problem that we know how to solve--finding a pattern within a line:

```
 $ tr 'C' '\n' <test.file | sed -n 's/.*A\(.*\)B\(.*$\)/\1 \2/p'
```

The `tr 'C' '\n'` command translates any "C" in the input into a newline character.  Thus, it is then necessary to just pipe it into a command that will output the text between A and B and between B and the end of the line.

If A, B, and C are regular expressions rather than simple characters, try:

```
sed -e 's/C/\n/g' < test.file | sed -n 's/.*A\(.*\)B\(.*\)/\1 \2/p'
```

This uses the same basic idea, but uses `sed` to create the newlines.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mention that A, B and C have to be regular expressions.
and afaik tr only works with single characters.

Comment: I updated it with a command that should work even for complex A,B, and C.

Answer (score 2):

[Awk](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) generalizes the notion of lines to record, which can be terminated by any character. Several implementations, such as [Gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), support an arbitrary regular expression as the record separator. Untested:

```
gawk -vRS='C' 'sub(/.*A/, "") && sub(/B.*/) {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line can fit into memory, then repeated use of the split function from Perl would work.  Otherwise, I would read the file in blocks (with the Perl sysread function) and process each block individually as above -- allowing for stings of interest to cross block boundaries.

Comment: it easily fits into memory.

i don't have any experience with perl.